# Swagger Can't read from file schemaValidationMessages

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm and tottaly new at Swagger and I'm trying to make my swagger documentation but I'm facing a problem here. I found a lot a questions similar to mine, but o couldn't understand what am I supposed to do to resolve this. The thing is, have already downloaded my swagger.json and swagger.yaml from the Swagger Editor, and followed the instructions in the [Swagger Instructions](https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#download-33) I tried changing the default API, but i get this error:

[image]

and if I click in ERROR i get this message: `{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file swagger.json"}]}`

I've searched here and in the internet, and I saw that people recommend disabling the validator in the index.html, but I couldn't find this options.

Here is my `index.html` code:

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Source+Code+Pro:300,600|Titillium+Web:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <style>
    html
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after
    {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
      margin:0;
      background: #fafafa;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
  <defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="unlocked">
          <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V6h2v-.801C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8z"></path>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
      <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
      <path d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
      <path d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
      <path d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z"/>
    </symbol>


    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
      <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
      <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"/>
    </symbol>

  </defs>
</svg>

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
<script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
</script>
</body>

</html
```

My folder structure is:

[image: Folder Structure]

The PetStore example worked fine when it was installed, so no problems in the installation. I'm looking for instructions here, I can't seem to find my way around this. How can I configure this so I can see my swagger.json or swagger.yaml?

Comment: I think Swagger UI 3.x does not support loading local files (`file:///...`). Does it work if you put your spec on a server (e.g. localhost) and load it from there?

Comment: @Helen I tried change to this `url: "localhost:4000/swagger.json"`, but still got the same screen but, without the ERROR button

Comment: Try `"http://localhost:4000/swagger.json"`

Comment: I've tried that too, but got the same result as my last comment. It doesn't make sense to me what's wrong

Comment: Do you also host UI from localhost or open it as a local file? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 6):

In your index.html file, inside window.onload function, add validatorUrl: null.

So your function should look like-

```
window.onload = function () {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "./swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    validatorUrl: null,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Swagger Validation in SwaggerConfig.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger().EnableSwaggerUi(c => { c.DisableValidator(); });
```

This would resolve the issue.